# how to set a background image as colorWithPatternImage in swift

Tags: uiview, swift

My questions is, is it possible to have a UIView display an image, and if so, how so I do it? All I can find is the `colorwithpatternImage` which no longer works with swift.

The code I am trying to use now is:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Refer to the [`UIColor` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621933-init).

In Swift, you have to call a convenience initializer. This is because in Swift, all Objective-C class methods which return an instance of their class become convenience initializers.

Here's how it looks in Swift:

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
```

`+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image` returns a `UIColor` instance, so it will become a convenience initializer in Swift. Similarly, `UIImage imageNamed:` becomes `init(patternImage image: UIImage!)`.

Comment: thanks for correct answers. one thing more. image for background can't fit to label, only some portion of background image were showned. please help me that how this image will fit to label size?

Comment: @IbadUrRahman yeah, I had the same issue with creating a custom delete image on a tableview cell where the image was far too big. I made the image smaller and it just kinda goes into tile mode. 

I ended up just making it the exact size in photoshop since it doesn't act like an image on an UIImageView.

Comment: I am using the code above, but I am getting a white border around each repetition of the image. My image definitely doesn't include any border. Anyone else came across this issue?

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to this one:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background.png")
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)
```

Since setting image as backgroundColor would make it a litte blurry.

Answer (score 4):

Edited @User9527 's answer a bit. Not sure why it was down voted.. Worked great for me. Just added my own custom frame.

```
let frame = CGRectMake(10, 55, 45, 45)
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: frame)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg_image")
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying for layer property of an imageview, u should use something like this

```
userProfilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor(patternImage:UIImage(named: "yourimg.png")!).CGColor
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add optional binding for the above code to work. That is exclamation after UIImage as shown below.

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundSection.png")!)`

Comment: is there a way to make the image fit within the view dimensions!?

Answer (score 0):

This took me quite a bit of effort, capturing and passing along for reference. See below for full example of generation and use with swift.

**Reference Example**

- GitHub(jmr): [Texture Reference - '0_1_TextureRef'](https://github.com/justinmreina/0_1_TextureRef)

**Demo App**

[image]

**Code Excerpt**

Here is how a UIView is textured in the demo, see code for full listing -

```
func genTexturedView(_ view:UIView) {
    ...
    image.image = UIImage(named:"purple_example");
    view.addSubview(image);

    print("ViewController.genTexturedView():    Textured View added");

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "YourImage.png")!)